# Get specific object with the NGXS selector and use it in the template

Tags: angular, typescript, http, state, ngxs

I'm dispatching saved Settings from an API. A Setting has an 'ID' and a couple objects like 'numberOfUsers' etc. Furthermore I'm using NGXS for state management. 
I only want to get the 'numberOfUsers' and use it in my template. But for some reason my subscription is for a *millisecond* **undefined** and than has the data (see image). I also tried to map, but I really don't know what's the best practise here and how to get the data in my template.
**Here is my code:**

```
@Select(SettingsState.getSettings)
settings$!: Observable<Settings[]>;

settingsChanged!: Settings[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(new GetSettings(this.settingsId));

  this.settings$.subscribe((data: Settings[]) => {
        console.log('data', data);
        return this.settingsChanged = data;
      }
  );
}

console.log('settingsChanged', this.settingsChanged);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm suspecting you just need to `await` the result before you return it? Like this `return await this.settingsChanged = data;` or maybe like this, not sure what your setup looks like. `await this.settings$....`

Comment: Whatever is in state is what's going to come out of the subscription. I know that might sound simple/trivial, but the first time the component renders it might get the default state, which you might be setting to `null`. I think you need to use the observable in the template, and use the async pipe. This would also remove the need for the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may help!

**Filter** : is used to filter null responses.

**map**:  is used to get only the properties that you want.

```
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.settings$.pipe(map((data) => {
  if(data) {
  return {
    id: data.ID,
    attempts: data.numberOfUsers,
    key: data.others,
  }
  }}),
  filter(res => res && res != undefined)
  ).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log('data', data);
    alert(data.id);
    return this.settingsChanged = data;
  }
);
```

Working Example : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-pipe-filter-and-map?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Good luck.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. Are you sure this is syntactically correct?

Comment: @Oussail, this looks good to me too. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Richard.Davenport i have updated my answer with a working example

Comment: @Oussail, sorry I meant for my comment to be aimed at R2T8